# Constructor Optional Params

Tags: dart, flutter

Is there a way to set a constructor optional param?
I mean something like:

```
User.fromData(this._name, 
  this._email, 
  this._token, 
  this._refreshToken,  
  this._createdAt,  
  this._expiresAt,  
  this._isValid,  
  {this.id});
```

It indicates that

> Named option parameters can't start with an underscore.

But I need this field as private, so, I'm lost now.

Comment: Use [] instead of {}

Comment: What is use of Private variables which are defined with [ ] Kindly suggest. Thanks.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

You need to use a simple parameter and initialize your private field in initializer list.

```
class User {
  final String _id;
  final String _name;
  User.fromData(this._name, {required String id})
      : _id = id;
}
```

Comment: Case optional named parameters - I am using dart class in flutter and code is as: class MyDataObject {
  final int anInt;
  final String aString;
  final double aDouble;

  MyDataObject({
     this.anInt = 1,
     this.aString = 'Old!',
     this.aDouble = 2.0,
  });

} getting error that need to 'Add required keyword' before this.anInt = 1, this.aString = 'Old!' and this.aDouble = 2.0, Kindly suggest what is the issue and how can we fix it. Thanks.

Comment: You get this issue because the langage is now nullsafe (you have to add `?` for nullable types or use `required` before non-nullable named parameter). I updated the code snippet to make it work with nullsafety.

Comment: Thanks Alexandre for reply. I was looking for optional named parameters in class and got the correct solution for my requirement at https://stackoverflow.com/a/55769496/10329023

Answer (score 160):

This is a more general answer for future viewers.

### Positional optional parameters

Wrap the optional parameter with `[ ]` square brackets.

```dart
class User {

  String name;
  int age;
  String home;

  User(this.name, this.age, [this.home = 'Earth']);
}

User user1 = User('Bob', 34);
User user2 = User('Bob', 34, 'Mars');
```

Optional parameters need to be nullable if you don't provide a default value:

```dart
class User {

  String name;
  int age;
  String? home; //    <-- Nullable

  User(this.name, this.age, [this.home]);
}
```

### Named optional parameters

Wrap the optional parameter with `{ }` curly braces.

```dart
class User {

  String name;
  int age;
  String home;

  User(this.name, this.age, {this.home = 'Earth'});
}

User user1 = User('Bob', 34);
User user2 = User('Bob', 34, home: 'Mars');
```

The default for `home` is "Earth", but like before, if you don't provide a default then you need to change `String home` to `String? home`.

### Private fields

If you need private fields then you can use `[]` square brackets:

```dart
class User {
  int? _id;
  User([this._id]);
}

User user = User(3);
```

or do as the accepted answer says and use an initializer list:

```dart
class User {
  int? _id;
  User({int? id}) 
    : _id = id;
}

User user = User(id: 3);
```

### Named required parameters

Named parameters are optional by default, but if you want to make them required, then you can use the `required` keyword:

```dart
class User {
  final String name;
  final int age;
  final String home;

  User({
    required this.name,
    required this.age,
    this.home = 'Earth',
  });
}

User user1 = User(name: 'Bob', age: 34);
User user2 = User(name: 'Bob', age: 34, home: 'Mars');
```

Comment: Case optional named parameters - I am using dart class in flutter and code is as: class MyDataObject {
  final int anInt;
  final String aString;
  final double aDouble;

  MyDataObject({
     this.anInt = 1,
     this.aString = 'Old!',
     this.aDouble = 2.0,
  });

} getting error that need to 'Add required keyword' before this.anInt = 1, this.aString = 'Old!' and this.aDouble = 2.0, Kindly suggest what is the issue and how can we fix it. Thanks.

Comment: @Kamlesh, I'm not sure why you're getting that error. You can add the `required` keyword before them if you like but since you provide default values you don't need to. You would only need to if you removed the default values.

Comment: I've expanded the answer to include named required parameters as well as updating for null safety.

Comment: class User {

  String name;
  int age;
  String home;

  User(this.name, this.age, {this.home = 'Earth'});
}

User user1 = User('Bob', 34);
User user2 = User('Bob', 34, home: 'Mars'); Named optional parameter example made my day. It works. Thanks dear Suragch

Comment: In case someone struggled like me: If you want to make multiple parameters optional, wrap them together in the brackets, not each one individually

Answer (score 6):

In addition to great Suragch's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55769496/10595176) I wanted to mention `required` word. You can use it for multiple constructor or function named parameters to specify required ones.

```
class User {
  int _id;
  String _firstName;
  String _lastName;
  User({required int id, String firstName = "", String lastName}) 
    : _id = id,  // required parameter
      _firstName = firstName,  // optional parameter with default value ""
      _lastName = lastName;  // optional parameter without default value
}

User user1 = User(id: 1);
User user2 = User(id: 2, firstName: "John");
User user3 = User(id: 3, lastName: "Snow");
```

Related Dart docs [here](https://dart.dev/null-safety/understanding-null-safety#required-named-parameters).

For Dart version <= 2.10 `@required` is an annotation and used with the @ prefix.

Comment: Case optional named parameters - I am using dart class in flutter and code is as: class MyDataObject {
  final int anInt;
  final String aString;
  final double aDouble;

  MyDataObject({
     this.anInt = 1,
     this.aString = 'Old!',
     this.aDouble = 2.0,
  });

} getting error that need to 'Add required keyword' before this.anInt = 1, this.aString = 'Old!' and this.aDouble = 2.0, Kindly suggest what is the issue and how can we fix it. Thanks.