# How to create null safe, default value constructor with Syntactic sugar

Tags: dart

How do I create a null safe constructor with Syntactic sugar that would set a default value if the provided value is null?

```
class Person {
  Person({
    required this.name, //Idealy, adding (?? "friend") instead of "required" should've worked but doesn't.
    required this.age,
  });
  String name;
  int age;
  greet() {
    print("Hello $name");
  }
}
```

So, I actually want something like this,

```
class Person {
  Person({
    this.name ?? "friend",
    this.age ?? 0,
  });
  String name;
  int age;
  greet() {
    print("Hello $name");
  }
}
```

But, as you know this is not valid in dart. So, how actually, should I achieve this?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52449508/constructor-optional-params

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Constructor Optional Params](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52449508/constructor-optional-params)

Comment: @Coder2195 yes, it seems the below answers from your given link, do indeed answer my question. Sorry, that I didn't see those answers at first, can I reselect your proposal?

Comment: yes I posted my answer as answer instead of comment

Comment: @CyberAvater Please update your question if the answer really is the one from Coder2195. The suggested solution does not handle the case of "that would set a default value if the provided value is null" described in your question right now. So if that case is not part of your problem, then it should not be part of the question.

Comment: I actually am sorry that I wasn't clear enough by the "proposal", what I meant was a prompt (by Stackoverflow) that suggests that the answer might be in a specified asked question. I answer no, but there is a hint to answer this question from one of those answers. I was only asking how to I reselect that as yes.

Anyhow, long story short, the answer provided by @julemand101 is very specific to this question (which is exactly what I needed to know), so that'll be the selected one. But, the suggested link from Coder2195 is very relevant to the question and should be helpful to know,

Comment: So, I'll just upvote that one as well, no need to extend this topic. And, I'm quite new myself here, so pardon if you felt offended.

Comment: @CyberAvater Ah ok that explains the situation. And no, I am not at all offended, but just confused about the comments. But it is clear now :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
class Person {
  Person({
    String? name,
    int? age,
  })  : this.name = name ?? "friend",
        this.age = age ?? 0;
  String name;
  int age;

  void greet() {
    print("Hello $name");
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

[Constructor Optional Params](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52449508/constructor-optional-params)
for selecting my proposal

select this as an answer (converted from comment with permission)

Comment: I don't think this answer this part of the question "that would set a default value if the provided value is null". So it is not a question of an optional named parameter but that we have a case where we do provide an argument but should handle null as input as the same as if no argument is given. No of the answers, in that link, provides an solution with that aspect.

Comment: but the creator of the post said so... it works

Comment: Then the creator of the question needs to rephrase the question since we can only assume that the written question is the one there needs to be answered.

Comment: He literally said: @Coder2195 yes, it seems the below answers from your given link, do indeed answer my question. Sorry, that I didn't see those answers at first, can I reselect your proposal? (which he ACCEPTS my answer)

Comment: I did saw that and then I wanted to give a comment to your answer so other people would understand the difference between our two suggested solutions. I do not disagree that if this solves the problem then cool. But then the question needs to be changed so other people does not think that this is the solution to the problem described right now.

Comment: so what are you saying, the creator needs to edit the question or what

Comment: Yes... As I said in my second comment. To make it more clear I have made a comment now on the question also :)

Comment: isnt the question clear enough though? option parameter right?

Comment: The question is clear. The problem is that if your comment solves the problem then the asked question is plain wrong. The question is about "that would set a default value if the provided value is null" with a rather clear code example. So the asker wants to have default values for named parameters but wants to handle the case that if a named argument is given but the given value is `null` then it should also default to some default value.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/233395/discussion-between-coder2195-and-julemand101).

Answer (score 1):

You can also use *default values* for your optional parameters:

```dart
class Person {
  Person({
    this.name = "friend",
    this.age = 0,
  });
  String name;
  int age;
  greet() {
    print("Hello $name");
  }
}
```

The parameter is not *required*, and if you don't pass it, it gets the default value. If you *do* pass an argument, it must be non-null.