# Can't define constructor with optional parameters Dart

Tags: flutter, dart, constructor, optional-parameters

I can't define this constructor :

```
class Artists_Showroom extends StatefulWidget {
  Artists_Showroom( //error 1 here
      {Key key,
      @required this.lista,
      @required this.database,
      @required this.artistaCorrente,
      [this.color = null]}). //error 2 here on first square brachet
      : super(key: key);
  final List<Artista> lista;
  final Artista artistaCorrente;
  final Database database;
  final Color color;
```

Error 1 :

```
All final variables must be initialized, but 'color' isn't.
Try adding an initializer for the field.
```

Error 2 :

```
Expected to find '}'.
Expected an identifier.
```

It worked until now because I need to add an optional parameter (in this case it's a color). I just never used optional parameters so I don't know how to declare them.

I did some researches and tried different solutions from StackOverflow but no one working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't have `Positional` optional parameters `[]` and `Named` optional parameters `{}` at the same time. Have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55769496/9936384).
If you want too keep your `Named` parameters you can do the following.

```
class Artists_Showroom extends StatefulWidget {
  const Artists_Showroom({
    Key key,
    @required this.lista,
    @required this.database,
    @required this.artistaCorrente,
    this.color,
  }) : super(key: key);

  final List<Artista> lista;
  final Artista artistaCorrente;
  final Database database;
  final Color color;
}
```

Comment: Ok but this time I need to pass "null" value each time I call the constructor right?

Comment: No you don't. If you don't pass anything then it is implicity null. Just call it like `Artis_Showroom(lista: lista, database:database, artistaCorrente: artistaCorrente)` and the color is then `null`.

Comment: Perfect explanation, I don't know why dart docs aren't clear like you